# There are 3 restaurants in a town...

Tags: probability

There are 3 restaurants in a  town.   Every evening, Mary randomly chooses a restaurant to go for a dinner.  What is the probability that after seven days, there will be a restaurant whichMary visited exactly 4 times?

I'm having trouble calculating this... I think the denominator to the probability can be represented as 3^7

the numerator though I'm struggling with...

basically, she needs to have visited one restaurant 4 out of 7 nights... and the other 3 nights go to one of the other restaurants

is it simply 2^3

so

2^3 / 3^7

Comment: It is rather more than that.  $\frac{2^3}{3^7}$ is the probability she goes to restaurant A on Sunday, Monday Tuesday and Wednesday, and then to the other restaurants on Thursday, Friday and Saturday.  So can you see the possibilities you missed?

Comment: maybe something like (7 choose 4) *(3 choose 1) ? is that a better start? choose 4 of the nights to which she visited and multiply by 3 for choosing the restaurant

Comment: That looks better to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Choose the restaurant to visit four times ($_3C_1$) then the four days she visits that one on $(_7C_4)$.

Then, choose the restaurants visited on the other days. (How many ways can she do this? None of them can be the restaurant she visited four times.)

(spoiler)

> Three days she has a choice of two restaurants, so $2^3=8$.

Then divide by the total number of ways, which you figured out as $3^7$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of X~Bin(7, 1/3) and you're looking for P(X = 4) which is $${7 \choose 4}(1/3)^4 \cdot (2/3)^3$$

Comment: There is also the choice of the favorite restaurant.